# iTunesConnect error: arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes, arm64

I'm trying to upload my first iOS app to iTunesConnect. Problem is, whenever I'm uploading it, it emails me the next error:

> Dear developer, We have discovered one or more issues with your recent
>   delivery for "Project". To process your delivery, the
>   following issues must be corrected: Missing 64-bit support - Beginning
>   on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must
>   include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June
>   1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To
>   enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode
>   build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary
>   with both 32-bit and 64-bit code. Once these issues have been
>   corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary. Regards, The
>   App Store team

I did the right arm64 set up but it's permanently failing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like Apple's services are unstable now, for example http://thenextweb.com/apple/2015/03/11/the-apple-app-store-is-having-problems-and-itunes-connect-is-down/

Comment: iTunes it's working today..and the problem persists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See attached screen-shot. Specially the red marked one.[image: good settings]

Comment: Thanks! You were right.. just I wasn't on the right target.